# 'MenuButton' TargetType does not match type of element 'Button'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

A UserControl has a button with `Style="{StaticResource MenuIconByttonStyle}"` defined in App.xaml, but using this UserControl in a window xaml gives error :

> 'MenuButton' TargetType does not match type of element 'Button'

Not sure what MenuButton refers to, as I can't find that defined anywhere. 
If I use StaticResource `MenuIconButtonStyle2`, or `FlatToolbarButton`, I don't get this error.

Why may this be?

App.xaml :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FlatToolbarButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>

    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MenuIconButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlatToolbarButton}" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="#333333">
                            <Border CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="#333333">
                                <Image  Source="{StaticResource MenuIcon}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/> 
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="Aqua">
                                    <Border CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Aqua">
                                        <Image  Source="{StaticResource MenuIcon}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>


        <Style x:Key="MenuIconButtonStyle2" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlatToolbarButton}" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource  MenuIconBrush}"/> 
        </Style>
```

TradeListUC.xaml:

```
   <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="18"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel  Grid.Row="0" Background="#333333"  >

        <Label x:Name="TitleLabel" FontSize="12" Content="Trade List" Height="16" Width="100" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="4,0,0,0" Foreground="White"   />
        <StackPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Right"   HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal"   >
            <TextBox x:Name="SymbolEntryTb" Width="100" Margin="0,0,1,0"  
                     Background="#999999" BorderBrush="#AAAAAA" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Right"    Padding="0,-1,0,0" />
            <Button x:Name="MenuBtn" Style="{StaticResource MenuIconButtonStyle}">

            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml :

```
 <TabItem Header="Trades">
      <Grid>
         <UC:TradeListUC/>
      </Grid>
 </TabItem>
```

Comment: What happens if you add a `TargetType` to the `ControlTemplate`?

Comment: @grek40 Made no difference. But just found out renaming the style key to anything different from `MenuIconButtonStyle` made the error go away. Very odd..

Comment: You should clean your solution of all generated files (complete rebuild is not enough). But maybe `MenuIconButtonStyle` is already used somewhere in the framework. When a simple rename makes all the difference, there's a lot of possibilities. Maybe I can try to reproduce this later, but not right now.

Comment: @grek40 Clean solution made no difference. I couldn't find any other reference to the name. Not critical though since it works with different name.

Comment: @bretddog: You probably have another `MenuIconButtonStyle` with a different `TargetType` defined somewhere. Search for it in your solution. Are you using any third-party packages?